# R Markdown - changing font size of one specific header item (not all) in html output

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown, knitr

I am using R Markdown in RStudio and the knit HTML option to create HTML output. I use multiple header levels (1, 1.1, etc...) and tabset to produce the same header and code but using alternative dataset (e.g., subset A, subset B).

My issue is that, using tabset with headers, the numbered header font sizes do not match anymore. For example 2.1a in the example below should be the same font size as 1.1 but is currently display with a smaller font as it is one # level lower (## for 1.1 and ### for 2.1a).

```r
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

# 1. Header lvl1 
## 1.1 Header lvl2
# 2. Header lvl1{.tabset .tabset-pills}
## tab a
### 2.1a Header lvl2
### 2.2a Header lvl2
## tab b
### 2.1b Header lvl2
### 2.2b Header lvl2
```

I am looking for a way to homogenize font size of headers by their "assigned" level and not their # depth.
One trick that I found was to use in each lvl 2 header (1.1, 2.1a, 2.2a, etc..) : `### 2.1a <font size="5"> header name </font>`.
However I am using TOC and it modifies the TOC font size as well, which is an issue when using large font.
Any suggestions ?

Thank you in advance!